# npm install after npm install <package-name>?

Tags: npm

In a [project walkthrough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N7Mrj0WrvnM), the project is bootstrapped with Create React App, two packages are installed (`npm install react-bootstrap` and `npm install marked` are run), then npm install is run. I don't understand why you would run npm install at that point since when you do npm install, it downloads the package to node_modules (in addition to adding it as a dependency in package.json). In the walkthrough (at 5:20) the person says he's doing `npm-install` to install packages that are left over. That seems unnecessary; is it a mistake or is there some reason to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `npm install $package --save` adds a package to your package file and installs it. The command `npm install` installs all packages mentioned in your package file.

So the latter is run to install any packages that weren't named or dependencies of `react-bootstrap` and `marked`, but that were added to the package file (but not installed) by `create-react-app`.

So the workflow they use:

1. `create-react-app`: creates a project from a template, creating a package file and installing the necessary packages.
2. `npm install react-bootstrap --save`: add and install React-Bootstrap.
3. `npm install marked --save`: add and install Marked.
4. `npm install`: just once more to verify all packages are installed correctly.

I think they could've skipped step 4.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure how any packages needed for `create-react-app`, `react-bootstrap`, or `marked` could have been missed.
Just a note, `--save` is no longer needed to add dependencies to package.json as of npm 5; it's now done when running `npm install <package-name>` by default. https://blog.npmjs.org/post/161081169345/v500